# How do you add an <iFrame> from the CSS class of another website

Tags: html, css, iframe

We're trying to run this to show the Covid numbers on a website homepage (https://tholabiotech.com/ ) but are having a bit of an issue with ads running within the iFrame (Screenshot: https://ibb.co/hCSb3rR )... Is there a way to add an iFrame where the CSS element of the iFramed website is used so that it only shows the numbers section in the left of this screenshot of Screenshot: https://ibb.co/hCSb3rR - From: https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus )

Trying to fit the iFrame with CSS is a little problematic with responsiveness

```
<div id="divContainer" style="left: 50px; top: 90px;">
<div id="frameContainer" style="overflow:hidden;">
    <iframe src="https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/" scrolling="no" style="align-content: center; width: 790px; height: 800px; margin-top: -300px;">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: No, that is not possible. The Same Origin Policy forbids your page from reaching into the iframe and interacting with its content. You could only proxy this request via your server, and insert custom styling then. But that would be a rather unfair thing to do to begin with - if they finance their site with ads, then you should not steal their content and display it ad-free.

Comment: No you cant do that

Comment: That way is possible. However, i feel like can be so involving. You can try use the Worldometer API to display what you want[Covid-19 Daily Update API - Postman](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/4876530/SzRxUpPv#da78fc92-d559-4112-ae73-675b4222e69d)

Comment: It looks as though Worldometers don't provide an API to give you what you want. The answer in https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/17769/is-it-possible-to-download-worldometer-covid-19-country-data gives a suggestion of an alternative source.